# want to do the image side rounded corner with curve want to remove the line appearing in the image

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, paint

I am cropping the image side rounded corner with curve want to remove the line appearing in the image as you can see in the output screen mentioned in the post

am using quadTo to crop the arc shape and then applying arcTo to do the corners rounded(smooth) as mentioned in the reference image

reference image

[image]

ArcLayout.java

```
 import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Outline;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
    import android.graphics.RectF;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewOutlineProvider;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    public class ArcLayout extends FrameLayout {

        private ArcLayoutSettings settings;

        private int height = 0;

        private int width = 0;

        private Path clipPathOne;

        private Path clipPathOneCurv;

        private Path clipPathTwoCurv;

        private float radius = 0, margin = 0;

        private final RectF cornerRect = new RectF();


        public ArcLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context, null);
        }

        public ArcLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(context, attrs);
        }

        public void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            settings = new ArcLayoutSettings(context, attrs);
            settings.setElevation(ViewCompat.getElevation(this));
            radius = settings.getRadius();
            margin = settings.getMargin();

            /**
             * If hardware acceleration is on (default from API 14), clipPathOne worked correctly
             * from API 18.
             *
             * So we will disable hardware Acceleration if API < 18
             *
             * https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported
             * Section #Unsupported Drawing Operations
             */
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }
        }

        private Path createClipPath(int position) {
            final Path path = new Path();

            float arcHeight = settings.getArcHeight();

            switch (position) {
                case ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_BOTTOM_CURVE:
                    if (settings.isCropInside()) {
                        path.moveTo(0, 0);
                        path.lineTo(0, height);
                        path.quadTo(width / 2, height - 2 * arcHeight, width, height);
                        path.lineTo(width, 0);
                        path.close();
                    } else {
                        path.moveTo(0, 0);
                        path.lineTo(0, height - arcHeight);
                        path.quadTo(width / 2, height + arcHeight, width, height - arcHeight);
                        path.lineTo(width, 0);
                        path.close();
                    }
                    break;

                case ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_TOP_CURVE:
                    if (settings.isCropInside()) {
                        path.moveTo(0, height);
                        path.lineTo(0, 0);
                        path.quadTo(width / 2, 2 * arcHeight, width, 0);
                        path.lineTo(width, height);
                        path.close();
                    } else {
                        path.moveTo(0, arcHeight);
                        path.quadTo(width / 2, -arcHeight, width, arcHeight);
                        path.lineTo(width, height);
                        path.lineTo(0, height);
                        path.close();
                    }
                    break;


                case ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_LEFT_CURVE:
                    if (settings.isCropInside()) {
                        path.moveTo(width, 0);
                        path.lineTo(0, 0);
                        path.quadTo(arcHeight * 2, height / 2, 0, height);
                        path.lineTo(width, height);
                        path.close();
                    } else {
                        path.moveTo(width, 0);
                        path.lineTo(arcHeight, 0);
                        path.quadTo(-arcHeight, height / 2, arcHeight, height);
                        path.lineTo(width, height);
                        path.close();
                    }
                    break;
                case ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_RIGHT_CURVE:
                    if (settings.isCropInside()) {
                        path.moveTo(0, 0);
                        path.lineTo(width, 0);
                        path.quadTo(width - arcHeight * 2, height / 2, width, height);
                        path.lineTo(0, height);
                        path.close();
                    } else {
                        path.moveTo(0, 0);
                        path.lineTo(width - arcHeight, 0);
                        path.quadTo(width + arcHeight, height / 2, width - arcHeight, height);
                        path.lineTo(0, height);
                        path.close();
                    }
                    break;

            }

            return path;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
            super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
            if (changed) {
                calculateLayout();
            }
        }

        private void calculateLayout() {
            if (settings == null) {
                return;
            }
            height = getMeasuredHeight();
            width = getMeasuredWidth();

            if (radius > 0 && settings.getRounded_corn_pos() != ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_DEFAULT) {
                clipPathOne = roundedCornerPath(radius, settings.getRounded_corn_pos());
            }

            if (settings.getArc_position() != ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_DEFAULT) {


                if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                    if (settings.getArc_position() == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_BOTH_CURVE) {
                        clipPathOneCurv = createClipPath(ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_TOP_CURVE);
                        clipPathTwoCurv = createClipPath(ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_BOTTOM_CURVE);
                    } else {
                        clipPathOneCurv = createClipPath(settings.getArc_position());
                    }

                    ViewCompat.setElevation(this, settings.getElevation());
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && !settings.isCropInside()) {
                        ViewCompat.setElevation(this, settings.getElevation());
                        setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                            @Override
                            public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
                                if (settings.getArc_position() == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_BOTH_CURVE) {
                                    outline.setConvexPath(clipPathOneCurv);
                                    outline.setConvexPath(clipPathTwoCurv);
                                } else {
                                    //outline.setConvexPath(clipPathOneCurv);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));

            if (clipPathOneCurv != null) {
                canvas.drawPath(clipPathOneCurv, paint);
            }
            if (clipPathTwoCurv != null) {
                canvas.drawPath(clipPathTwoCurv, paint);
            }
            if (clipPathOne != null) {
                canvas.drawPath(clipPathOne, paint);
            }


            canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);


        }


        private Path roundedCornerPath(float cornerRadius, int position) {
            //path.rewind();
            Path path = new Path();
            final int width = getWidth();
            final int height = getHeight();
            final float twoRadius = cornerRadius * 2;
            cornerRect.set(-cornerRadius, -cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);

            if (position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_TOP_LEFT_ROUND || position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_TOP_ROUND || position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_ALL_ROUND) {
                cornerRect.offsetTo(0f, settings.getArcHeight());
                path.arcTo(cornerRect, 180f, 90f);
            } else {
                path.moveTo(0f, 0f);
            }

            if (position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT_ROUND || position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_TOP_ROUND || position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_ALL_ROUND) {
                cornerRect.offsetTo(width - twoRadius, settings.getArcHeight());
                path.arcTo(cornerRect, 270f, 90f);
            } else {
                path.lineTo(width, 0f);
            }

            if (position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT_ROUND || position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_BOTTOM_ROUND || position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_ALL_ROUND) {
                cornerRect.offsetTo(width - twoRadius, height - twoRadius);
                path.arcTo(cornerRect, 0f, 90f);
            } else {
                path.lineTo(width, height);
            }

            if (position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT_ROUND || position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_BOTTOM_ROUND || position == ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_ALL_ROUND) {
                cornerRect.offsetTo(0f, height - twoRadius);
                path.arcTo(cornerRect, 90f, 90f);
            } else {
                path.lineTo(0f, height);
            }

            path.close();
            return path;
        }

    }
```

rounded_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:gravity="center">


        <com.example.sonalsb.curved_img.ArcLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:arc_cropDirection="cropOutside"
            app:corner_position="top"
            app:corner_radius="12dp"
            app:arc_position="top"
            app:arc_height="8dp">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/cartoon" />

        </com.example.sonalsb.curved_img.ArcLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

attrs.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <declare-styleable name="ArcLayout">

            <attr name="arc_height" format="dimension" />

            <attr name="corner_radius" format="dimension"/>

            <attr name="corner_margin" format="dimension"/>

            <attr name="corner_position">
                <enum name="top_left" value="0"/>
                <enum name="top_right" value="1"/>
                <enum name="bottom_left" value="2"/>
                <enum name="bottom_right" value="3"/>

                <enum name="top" value="4"/>
                <enum name="bottom" value="5"/>
                <enum name="left" value="6"/>
                <enum name="right" value="7"/>

                <enum name="empty" value="9"/>
                <enum name="all" value="10"/>
            </attr>

            <attr name="arc_position">
                <enum name="bottom" value="0"/>
                <enum name="top" value="1"/>
                <enum name="left" value="2"/>
                <enum name="right" value="3"/>
                <enum name="both" value="4"/>

                <enum name="empty" value="99"/>
            </attr>
            <attr name="arc_cropDirection" format="enum">
                <enum name="cropInside" value="0" />
                <enum name="cropOutside" value="1"/>
            </attr>
        </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: As per your code, you are splitting the path cropping code to multiple cycles. Like top part cropped separately, bottom separately, etc. Instead you must create single path object with whole vector as one.

Comment: @MohammedAtif can you give me some references code for the path to create curved with rounded corners (in single path)